# Knowing the direction vector of an image

Tags: optimization, opencv, image-processing

I'm a bit rusty in Math, but I have a problem. I have a 2D Image that is projected on a floor, which has two characters like [A1]. I use a Mobile phone camera that detects, decodes those two characters. Consider, for example a vehicle that has that camera passed through those two characters, one time forward, and one time backward over the the two characters [A1]. In both ways, to detect the characters each, I have to rotate it 180*, then do NCC with the characters template each frame which is computational  consuming. Is there a better way or an optimized way to do that and save the rotation,..etc. ?

Is there also a way to know from an Image that is projected on the floor, the directional vector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are other ways to detect "features" on a image, with matching descriptors (SURF-Speeded-Up Robust Feature or SIFT-Scale Invariant Feature Transform) that are scale and rotational invariant.

at this [link](http://www.chrisevansdev.com/computer-vision-opensurf.html) you can find some implementations for C#, Java (ImageJ) and C++
OpenCV has also several implementation of the algorithm.

The idea is to extract descriptors from the template image and compare them with the target image without the need to rotate or scale it.

hope it helps

Comment: but after getting the features, can I get detect the two characters after that, even if the camera sees A1 but inverted in the Y position ?.  Kindly note that I'm working on an Embedded ARM board, so speed would be a great issue, do you think that method is fast ?

Comment: as I said the algorithm is rotational invariant, so you should have no problem even if the image is upside down. of course what u can obtain is a matching between descriptors, if u need to read the chars like OCR it's another story.

Comment: you're welcome :) just reading now about the performance issue. SURF and SIFT should be faster, if I'm not wrong, than NCC. even faster if u do not need it as rotation invariant. there are option for SURF where u can get upright descriptors only (will save some time by not calculating the orientation vectors). otherwise I'd suggest u to make some low level optimization on the algorithm using SIMD instructions or using GPU cuda if available (better check what has already been done on OpenCV)

Comment: @JonnField, so after detecting the features for example char C, against C1, should I make cross-correlation to identify C ?